# String replace to html tag in Angular 13

Tags: javascript, angular

I am beginner Angular developer.

i have this code:

```
export class KoniecComponent implements OnInit {

  ....
  wiadomosc: string;
  urlView: string;

  constructor(
    private cService: CService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.registerC();
  }

  registerC(): void {
    this.cService.saveC(this.szkoda).subscribe(
      wynik => {
       
        const json = JSON.stringify(wynik);
        let txt = JSON.parse(json);

        if(txt.result_info != "" && txt.result_info != null)
        {
          let msg = txt.result_info;
          let url = txt.pm;
          this.urlView = txt.pm;
          this.wiadomosc = msg.replace(txt.number, '<b>'+txt.number+'</b>');
        }
        else {
          ...............
        }
      },
      error => {
        .......
      }
    );
  }

}
```

I have problem with this line:

this.wiadomosc = msg.replace(txt.number, '**'+txt.number+'**');

In result i have 'b' tabs - not bolded text.

How can i repeir it? Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load rich html text in angular then interpolation will not work
you need to set it inside innerHTML attribute like this.
`<span [innerHTML]="wiadomosc"></span>` this will load `<b>test</b>` **test** as bold in DOM

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use like this.
`this.wiadomosc = msg.replace(txt.number, '<b>{{txt.number}}</b>');`

Comment: It's not help :( Now in result i have: blablabla <b>{{txt.number}}</b> blablabla